# c#-Any disadvantages if Static event is called from static constructor

Tags: c#

Are there any disadvantages to assigning static events from static constructors?

For example:

```
public class static Test()
{
    static Test()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_DomainUnload;
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: MemoryLeak, every call to test would subscribe more and more events...

Comment: @LeonBarkan: that's not a method. It's a constructor.

Comment: Oops... :) my mistake

Comment: Normally events are registered in constructors like the way you did it.  So there is nothing wrong,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there is any disadvantages using ...

No, subscribing to an event is fine.

Raising it would be problematic but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Can you explain how it is problematic and why it doesn't apply here?

Comment: Problematic: it's like the more general rule is that an instance constructor should not call any virtual members. A (static) event is similar, the handler should be able to assume a fully constructed class to work with.